# Android Tv RecyclerView set next focus of its item

Tags: java, android

I am working on android Tv, In our Fragment there the two Horizontal Recyclerview, when I scroll First Recyclerview using D-pad in Right direction, it scrolls well and when I come to last focus item of its Recycler view, Focus automatically goes down to second Recycler view item.

How to prevent this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="false"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstRelativeGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="755dp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gridView2"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:nextFocusRight="@null"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/home_textview" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondRelativeGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.MyHorizontalGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="754dp" />


    <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.MyHorizontalGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView4"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/gridView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="-2dp"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

It might be late but for any one still looking for solution:

You should write your own logic while searching for next focus happens and supply the last view as next focus item if in the end of list OR you may modify the logic according to your needs. For Ex:

```
override fun onInterceptFocusSearch(focused: View?, direction: Int): View? {
    val position = getPosition(focused)
    val count = itemCount
    lastKnownPosition = position
    return if (position == count - 1 && direction == View.FOCUS_RIGHT) {
        focused
    } else {
        super.onInterceptFocusSearch(focused, direction)
    }
}
```

And this method will be part of your layout manager.

Comment: Great answer. I have a problem the other way. I need to pass the focus on the menu on the left. When nested recyclerviews are scrolled at position 0 the focus goes correctly. The problem appears when one of the nested recyclerview is in a different position, then the focus first goes down or up. After scroll the nested recyclerview to position 0, focus moved to the left menu. Do you have an idea how to force the focus to pass immediately to the left menu?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the `focusable` attribute of the `recyclerview` to `false`

```
recyclerview.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am posting this answer very late , but there is one way you can do it is , in Adapter class check if the item is first , and set the nextFocusLeftId to itself. 
for example. 
itemview.setnextFocusLeftId(itemview.gedId)
do the same for the last element of the recycler view.